# Nvidia GPU passthrough fail with code 43

Tags: gpu, nvidia, kvm, vfio

I'm currently trying to pass a nvidia GPU to Windows 10 guest using qemu 2.5 and libvirt 1.3.5.

I see "Error 43" on Nvidia GPU in Device Manager.

I had tried to hide the hypervisor by adding "kvm=off" and "hv_vendor_id=123456780ab", but it does not work for me. I searched in google and people solved the problem in this way.

And I also saw Virtual Machine : Yes in task manager.

1. Did I use in the wrong way? I can pass a AMD gpu to windows guest(AMD does not check the kvm virtualization).
2. Can I spoof nvidia in other way?

My system information:

```
#uname -a
Linux ns.mqcache.net 4.2.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Aug 30 21:25:29 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#/root/qemu25/qemu/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.5.1.1, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

GPU:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 620 OEM] (rev a1)
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

libvirt.xml

```
<domain xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0" type="kvm">  
  <name>win10</name>  
  <os> 
    <type machine="q35">hvm</type>  
    <boot dev="hd"/>  
    <boot dev="cdrom"/> 
  </os>  
  <features> 
    <acpi/>  
    <apic/>  
    <hyperv>
      <vendor_id state='on' value='1234567890ab'/>
    </hyperv>
    <kvm>
      <hidden state='on'/>
    </kvm>
  </features>   
  <clock offset="localtime"> 
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>  
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>  
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/> 
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>  
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>  
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>  
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>  
  <vcpu current="4">4</vcpu>  
  <cpu mode="host-passthrough"> 
    <topology sockets="1" cores="4" threads="1"/> 
  </cpu>  
  <memory>8388608</memory>  
  <currentMemory>8388608</currentMemory>  
  <devices> 
    <emulator>/root/qemu25/qemu/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>  
    <disk device="disk" type="file"> 
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>  
      <source file="/root/vm/win10/image.qcow2"/>  
      <target bus="virtio" dev="vda"/> 
    </disk>  
    <sound model="ac97"/>  
    <interface type="bridge"> 
      <mac address="fa:16:3e:81:00:03"/>  
      <source bridge="eucabr"/>  
      <model type="virtio"/>  
      <driver name="qemu"/>  
      <alias name="net0"/> 
    </interface>  
    <hostdev mode="subsystem" type="pci" managed="yes"> 
      <source> 
        <address domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x1"/>
      </source> 
    </hostdev> 
  </devices>  
  <qemu:commandline> 
    <qemu:arg value="-machine"/>  
    <qemu:arg value="smm=off"/>  
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>  
    <qemu:arg value="ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1"/>  
    <qemu:arg value="-device"/>  
    <qemu:arg value="vfio-pci,host=02:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on"/>  
    <qemu:arg value="-vga"/>  
    <qemu:arg value="none"/>  
  </qemu:commandline> 
</domain>
```

qemu command

```
/root/qemu25/qemu/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-name win10 \
-machine q35,accel=kvm,usb=off \
-cpu host,kvm=off,hv_relaxed,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff,hv_vapic,hv_time,hv_vendor_id=blah \
-m 2048 \
-realtime mlock=off \
-smp 2,sockets=1,cores=2,threads=1 \
-no-user-config \
-nodefaults  \
-rtc base=localtime \
-no-shutdown \
-boot strict=on \
-device i82801b11-bridge,id=pci.1,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x1e \
-device pci-bridge,chassis_nr=2,id=pci.2,bus=pci.1,addr=0x1 \
-drive file=/root/vm/win10/snap.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=qcow2 \
-device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.2,addr=0x2,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 \
-k en-us \
-device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.2,addr=0x4 \
-machine smm=off \
-device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 \
-device vfio-pci,host=02:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=02:00.1,bus=root.1,addr=00.1 \
-msg timestamp=on \
-vga none
```

Look forward to your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass copy of unmodified videocard ROM to VM.

- You need a secondary GPU that you can use as the primary for this
  process. **You cannot dump a clean copy of the BIOS without having the 
  passthrough GPU as a secondary card**
- Put the extra card in the primary slot and the intended passthrough card in another pci-e port and bootup.
- Find your intended GPU again via lspci -v. In my case it had about the same address.
- Now you can dump the ROM to a file:

  ```
  # echo "0000:05:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/unbind
  # cd /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:05\:00.0
  # echo 1 > rom 
  # cat rom > /home/username/KVM/evga_gtx970.dump
  # echo 0 > rom
  # echo "0000:05:00.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/bind
  ```

  In this case, 0000:05:00.0 is my PCI card address. You don't really need the bind step at the bottom since you'll be rebooting anyways.
- You can check the integrity of the ROM dump with this handy utility at https://github.com/awilliam/rom-parser. My rom looks like:

  ```
  # ./rom-parser evga_gtx970.dump
  Valid ROM signature found @0h, PCIR offset 1a0h
          PCIR: type 0 (x86 PC-AT), vendor: 10de, device: 13c2, class: 030000
          PCIR: revision 0, vendor revision: 1
  Valid ROM signature found @f400h, PCIR offset 1ch
          PCIR: type 3 (EFI), vendor: 10de, device: 13c2, class: 030000
          PCIR: revision 3, vendor revision: 0
                  EFI: Signature Valid, Subsystem: Boot, Machine: X64
  Last image
  ```

  You should have both an EFI and a non-EFI x86 ROM in the dump ( I think most cards have both)
- Turn off the machine and put your GTX 1070 back in the primary slot.
- After booting, edit your VM xml and in the  section for your GPU (if you have already assigned the GPU to the VM) there should be a  section. Add a file='path/to/dump/here' statement to it. My full section looks like:

  ```
  <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
    <source>
      <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </source>
    <rom bar='on' file='/home/username/KVM/evga_gtx970.dump'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
  </hostdev>
  ```

  This will have the VM start the card with that BIOS instead of whatever the kernel gives it.

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/5sh41p/any_other_reasons_for_nvidia_driver_code_43/)

**Please note that you have to use OVMF (EFI) because SeaBIOS does not use card ROM properly.**

Comment: For me, dumping the BIOS this way worked, but dumping through GPU-Z produced a BIOS that didn't work.  Yet rom-parser says both are valid.  Working BIOS is 126K, non-working BIOS is 253K.

Comment: The card I am passing through is my secondary card. I already have my host machine ignoring it with vfio. There is nothing to dump when I start up my host machine unless I have booted into the host computer, then I can dump the rom from that GPU. Is this different than what you described?

Comment: Not sure I understand your case. Could you explain with a bit more details, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on OVMF or some other UEFI, make sure to triple-check that your card is UEFI-ready, especially on stuff that is older than ~2014.

I was under false impression that mine was (GTX 770), while, in fact, it wasn't (looked at the wrong version of ROM online) and wasted almost 2 days ripping my hair out. Look up UEFI support [like so](http://vfio.blogspot.com/2014/08/does-my-graphics-card-rom-support-efi.html) and look for ROM updates [here](https://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/).

I flashed my card, but I think you can put an UEFI-enabled ROM as `romfile=`. It appears that [other manufacturers' ROMs could work too](http://vfio.blogspot.com/2014/08/does-my-graphics-card-rom-support-efi.html?showComment=1409513460405#c2224731726912136763), if yours doesn't have an UEFI fix for you.

Comment: Indeed this "false impression" was the problem in my case. I went to that site, downloaded the latest firmware for my card model and, BAM!, it worked.